# Publisher and location not printing - biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have the below `biblatex` database. In the `book` publisher and location is not printing in PDF. And also direct `utf8` character (like Δ) is not printing in PDF. How to solve this?

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel,hyperref,fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes,microtype}%International Handling of Quotes
\usepackage[natbib=true,bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric,sorting=none,maxbibnames=4]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{{#1}}% Remove vol text

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ipab730bbib1,
 author ={James Gates S Jr and Jellal A and Hassan Saidi E L and Schreiber M},
 year={2004},
 title ={The expansion of arbitrary functions in terms of eigenfunctions of the operator\textit{−} Δ\textit{u} + \textit{cu}},
 journaltitle ={J. High Energy Phys.},
 note={JHEP11(2004)075},
}

@book{ipab730bbib2,
 author ={Borcea L and Druskin V and Guevara Vasquez F and Mamonov A},
 year ={2011},
 location={Cambridge},
 publisher={Cambridge University Press},
 chapter ={Resistor network approaches to electrical impedance tomography},
 title={Inverse Problems and Applications: Inside Out II},
 volume={vol 60},
 pages={55−118},
}
\end{filecontents}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    pdfencoding=auto
}

\setmainfont{TimesLTStd}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

I have using in command/terminal `latexmk -lualatex -f filename.tex`.

Comment: Could you perhaps use a font that others have access to? As it sits I cannot test your document as I don't have the font.

Comment: @daleif: We can test `times` or `times new roman` font.

Comment: Dropping the font, I have no issues with Δ, and the book publisher seems to be printed just fine. Might simply be an issue of an incomplete font?

Comment: Note that neither `times` or `times new roman` are available on all systems (I'm on Linux). As mentioned, it seems to woth if I remove `\setmainfont{TimesLTStd}` to just use the default

Comment: @daleif: I have using `windows` and unable to get `Δ` and `publisher name` and `location`. My `biber` version is 2.16 and `biblatex` version is `3.16`. Your version please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have `TimesLTStd` on my machine, but if I change the font to

```
\setmainfont{TimesNewRoman}
```

here is what I get with `biblatex` v3.16 and Biber 2.16

[image: Screenshot of output with Delta and publisher and location.]

Note that there is a capital Delta in entry [1] and `publisher` and `location` data in [2].

Whether or not the Delta appears will depend on your font. It will only come up if your font actually contains a Delta. If not, it might not appear and only cause a warning.

Note that in this case I believe `\textit{−} Δ\textit{u} + \textit{cu}` is a bad way to encode something that should be in math mode. The title of `ipab730bbib1` should read

```
title = {The expansion of arbitrary functions in terms of
         eigenfunctions of the operator~{\(-\Delta u +cu\)}},
```

There are some other details I would change with your entries. Here's what I would do

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none, maxbibnames=4]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{#1}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    pdfencoding=auto
}
\setmainfont{TimesNewRoman}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ipab730bbib1,
  author = {Gates, Jr., James S. and Jellal, A. and Hassan Saidi, E. L.
            and Schreiber, M.},
  year   = {2004},
  title  = {The expansion of arbitrary functions in terms of
            eigenfunctions of the operator~{\(-\Delta u +cu\)}},
 journal = {J. High Energy Phys.},
 volume  = {2004},
 number  = {11},
 eid     = {75},
}
@incollection{ipab730bbib2,
  author    = {Liliana Borcea and Vladimir Druskin
               and Guevara Vasquez, Fernando and Alexander V. Mamonov},
  title     = {Resistor Network Approaches to Electrical Impedance Tomography},
  booktitle = {Inverse Problems and Applications: Inside Out~{II}},
  editor    = {Gunther Uhlmann},
  year      = {2011},
  location  = {Cambridge},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  series    = {MSRI Publications},
  number    = {60},
  pages     = {55-118},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

[image: James S. Gates Jr., A. Jellal, E. L. Hassan Saidi and M. Schreiber. ‘The expansion of arbitrary functions in terms of eigenfunctions of the operator −∆u + cu ’. In: J. High Energy Phys. 2004.11, 75 (2004).//Liliana Borcea, Vladimir Druskin, Fernando Guevara Vasquez and Alexander V. Mamonov. ‘Resistor Network Approaches to Electrical Impedance Tomography’. In: Inverse Problems and Applications: Inside Out II. Ed. by Gunther Uhlmann. MSRI Publications 60. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2011, pp. 55–118.]

Comment: I have need `book` some structure format with `numeric` style. Need to print in PDF `name`, `year without brackets`, `title` etc...

Comment: So i have defined \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{location}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{publisher}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pages}%
  \finentry}
in the `biblatex.cfg` format. It's correct way or wrong?

Comment: @Balaji In general I'd say that a complete redefinition of a bibliography driver is often overkill. The desired effect can often be obtained with more subtle changes that do not change that much. In the code example `\printfield{location}` and `\printfield{publisher}` are wrong and explain the output you are seeing: Both `location` and `publisher` are list fields and need to be printed with `\printlist`, not with `\printfield`.

Comment: I would like to add `Ed` before the `editor`. How to do this? I had reviewed `biblatex.def` and unable to find.

Comment: @Balaji Ask a new question with an MWE and the exact requirements. As mentioned above rewriting the driver is the most radical solution, but needs a lot of copy-and-pasting from the right places if done correctly. Bare `\print...` commands are generally not enough.

Comment: I have created new question <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597690/before-ed-add-every-editor>